# Using UiPath reading date from Excel form to web app - date read in wrong order

Tags: excel, date, web, uipath

Here is the Excel form
[image]

year has 6 spaces so I added "00" in my workflow and the date isn't included so I added it separately here follows the code:

[image]

this is then how the first date is read into my web application
[image]

I am pretty new to UiPath and was wondering if anyone can help me with reading this as it is suppose to say 2016/11/20 14:20

I got 1120/02/01 06:20 but was expecting 2016/11/20 14:20 to be the output

Comment: I am not sure about your steps. It sounds you have trouble to parse the Date, right? So have a look here https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parseexact?view=net-7.0